# How to set bundle product renderer in custom module?

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, renderer

I want to get bundle product options: [like this](https://prnt.sc/l4q2xn)

I have added setTemplate `bundle/options.phtml` file with `Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle` class now i am getting message :

> There is no defined renderer for "radio" option type

i know that i have to set all renderer type(select,checkbox,multi and radio)

but how can i set all renderer types ?